How can i generate perlin noise as a material so i can change it in the shading window

i want this as a random noise material texture for a model however i do not know how to make it a material is there anyway to make it?

This question is similar to: How to generate Perlin Noise for materials. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] your question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
